# Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, gdb

I have just installed VS Code on my Windows and started to debug some basic C++ code. I have followed this article to set up my VSC: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw, and I encountered this error when trying to debug.

This is my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/Admin/projects/helloworld",
      "program": "c:/Users/Admin/projects/helloworld/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe", //I think the problem should be here LOL 
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have just started to use VSC for 10 minutes. Please give me the easiest and most accessible solutions for newbies. Thank you for your understanding <3

Comment: Did you try what it says [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_check-your-mingw-installation)?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried and reinstalled GDB too

Comment: But if you followed that document, why doesn't your `miDebuggerPath` have the value `"C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe"` as it is in there?

Comment: Cuz I already have my gdb.exe available in C:\MinGW\bin. Or is this path wrong??

Comment: If debugging works with this gdb (have you tried this?), then I would expect it also works with vscode.

Comment: It didn't work, I tried to change the path to "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe" but the result still the same.